# How do I add two 'unused fields in a structure in c?

Tags: c, structure

I want to send 8 bytes structure and since I dont have any valid member I just wanna add two unused fields which are of 4 and 2 bytes .

My code below is throwing up an error `duplicate member 'unused'`

```
typedef struct
{
  uint16_t    leakRatemTm;
  uint16_t    unused;
  uint32_t    unused;
} stuct_t;
```

How do I actually add multiple unused fields in a structure.

Thanks

Comment: The word `unused` is not a keyword or special to the compiler in any way, so you need to use different names for the members

Comment: What about `unusedX` where `X` is any integer in ascending order. Or instead, an array `char unused[size of unused block]`?

Comment: Note that, without additional instructions to your compiler, this code may not create an 8-byte structure as you expect. The compiler may pad the values for alignment reasons.

Comment: Why do you need this `struct` to be 8 bytes?  What's the actual problem that you're trying to solve?

Comment: I want to send 8 bytes of packets over CAN

Comment: I often see things like `reserved1`, `reserved2`, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use an array of char to pad with how many bytes you want. Use this in combination with the attribute packed:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)); 
{
  uint16_t    leakRatemTm;
  uint8_t     unused[6]
} stuct_t;
```

If you need gaps you can do something like this:

```
typedef struct __attribute__((packed)); 
{
  uint16_t    leakRatemTm;
  uint8_t     unused1[1]; //1byte gap
  uint16_t    otherVar;
  uint8_t     unused2[3]; //Fill till 8bytes
} stuct_t;
```